# Stop Vue Components being render in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have fresh installed Laravel application also I installed npm, now every page I try to load this file will load instead `ExampleComponent.vue`

`app.js`

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

`ExampleComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

## Question

As I don't have plan to use VueJs and I also need to see my actual pages that I'm created, **how I stop VueJs** of being render in my application?

Answer (score 3):

In your `app.js` remove everything after the bootstrap include, then recompile using `npm run dev`.

However, by default Laravel does nothing with Vuejs. Because it has no html elements on the page with id `#app`. Check your `resources/views` directory, the default blade file is `welcome.blade.php`.

To be exact about the flow:

- your routes file indicates how to handle requests and to which controller
- the controller responsible for the route will (probably) serve a blade view
- the blade view will be parsed, if it has an `#app` element and `app.js` binds Vue to `#app` Vue will take over.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for respond. I removed my node_modules folder and copied from my other project. When i run npm run dev it gives me error i searched for it and found that is path issue in my packages.json file so i tried that still getting error. About app id when you run auth command it creates new blades which their layouts included #app thats why i see my component loads everywhere, any idea about cross env error when running npm run dev?

Comment: I see, could be that the auth scaffolding uses vue, if you don't want to use Vue you might also need to use a different authentication method.

Recompile before dropping the packages from the package.json.

Comment: What if i just remove #app from layouts? Would that makes any problem in future?

Comment: That could work, unless these views rely on vue behaviour for their workings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using vue.js, you may safely remove the `#app` div tag from your blade. Also, dont forget to **remove** the script to load `app.js`. This script is unnecessary and since it is mainly used when you’re working with vue.js only.

So now, you will be working with normal php file (powered with blade syntax).

Hope this helps.